# How to add a 10px space around a tableViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to create a tableViewCell with a 10px spacing around it so the cell doesn't touch the edges of the screen.  I tried doing something like this I saw on another stackOverflow post in my cellForRowAtIndexPath but all I got was a black screen once I ran it in simulator:

```
 cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

    let whiteRoundedView : UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: self.view.frame.size.width - 20, height: 188))

    whiteRoundedView.layer.backgroundColor = CGColor(colorSpace: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), components: [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.8])
    whiteRoundedView.layer.masksToBounds = false
    whiteRoundedView.layer.cornerRadius = 10

    cell.contentView.addSubview(whiteRoundedView)
    cell.contentView.sendSubview(toBack: whiteRoundedView)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that it's better assign this 10px from storyboard (or xib).
You can insert a leading space constraint in your UIView (designed in your tableViewCell).
So automatically you no longer work with frames that which often gives problem...

Comment: How in storyboard can you set a border around a cell like this

Comment: I get what you mean now,  I added another view inside my contentview which housed all my ui elements and added constraints equalling 10px to the edges of the content view from the new view I just created.

Answer (score 0):

You should bring your whiteRoundedView to the front of the contentView. Right now the whiteRoundedView is behind the cell's contentView.

```
cell.contentView.bringSubview(toFront: whiteRoundedView)
```